# API for Image Similarity Detection

Tags: image, api, image-processing

I know that questions having `code` is most relevant here at SO. However I have a question which is more related to API/Web service. I read the recommendation and so I am asking this based on the guidelines mentioned in it.

We are building an online image asset management application is a mashup app, that allows customers to store data in the cloud and share/transfer between multiple drive services like GDrive, Amazon Cloud, Flick etc. It also allows for minimal curation and corrections.

Since many of our customers will be our service as a low-cost bulk storage system specially aligned for image assets, we provide them various ways of grouping images. Currently it includes exif dates and filenames. We are adding geotags to it. One feature we are really interested in, is having images grouped based on `similarity`. We are looking at APIs or services that can either be paid or free to which we can feed a bunch of images and we get recommendations based on similarity.

I have been checking online but I do not see any "established" service provider out there. The [LTU engine](https://www.ltutech.com/in-action/online-applications/) is mostly for ecommerce search such as similar dresses etc. Most others I found were for copyright infringement and brand detection services. There is an [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/image-similarity-search-wanted/) from John Resign,who was searching for the same thing way back in 2012, but based on the comments I do not think he found anything good.

My scenario is something like this - say a customer has a thousand images uploaded - some from the beach, some of his family and some other random. I would like the three categories of grouping to be the same as above (more or less).

Does anyone have experience in this kind of domain? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why tiney's matchengine service cant be used for your case. I am also looking for similar service and tineye seems to be a candidate. like load all the images to tineye and then query the collection with one of your images which will return best possible matches with match percentage which you can use to group the images

Answer (score 0):

You can get a basic one up pretty easily with caffe. Simply extract the fc7 layer of image net reference and calculate l2 distance. The results you are gonna get is similar to google image search. If you want something more, you need to finetune the model.